# Ridge regression parameter estimation in R

Tags: r, regression

I have seen about 16 parameter estimation methods in different research papers. How can these methods be implemented in R language using Monte Carlo simulation technique.

Comment: Just some clarifying questions which may hopefully make your question more specific (and hence get a better answer).  1) Are you talking about estimating the ridging parameter? 2) why do you want Monte Carlo simulations as opposed to other techniques(e.g. optimisation,MCMC)? 3) are you looking to account for the noise/error variance in your estimation method (i.e. the fact that the "ridged" betas won't exactly predict the response $y$)?

Answer (score 1):

The current go to tool for performing ridge regression in R (in my estimation) is the [glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) package. Default behavior is lasso regression: for ridge regression, set `alpha=0` when you call the `glmnet` or `cv.glmnet` functions for your regression. Setting alpha to any other value between 0 and 1 gives an elastic net penalty.

Additionally, base R has the `lm.ridge` function.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to homebrew your own ridge regression, you should probably start by picking which of the 16 parameter estimation methods you've come across you want to work with. Beyond that advice, your question is extremely broad and I don't really know what you want to hear.

A very simple way you could implement ridge regression would be to do a bayesian linear regression with normal priors centered at 0. Otherwise you will probably need to apply an optimization technique to the RSS loss function augmented with regularization penalty. I'm guessing the parameter estimation techniques you have read about largely pertain to this optimization problem.

Comment: Could you suggest why you prefer glmnet for ridge regression (out of the several packages that provide it)? (Bizarrely, ??"ridge" does not pull up glmnet.) It's common with R to have several packages offering more or less the same thing, and there's no systematic source of comparison info. (The r-sig-mixed-models FAQ does this for nlme, lme4, etc, but it seems to be a one-off.)

Comment: They're all just tools. I probably prefer glmnet because I learned it early (so I'm familiar with it), see people using it a lot (so there's some social confirmation that it's a good tool), and I'm also probably more likely to do a lasso regression anyway, so if I decide to change my model from lasso to ridge (or elastic net) instead of rebuilding my code to accommodate a different package, I literally just change a single parameter in my model.

Comment: initially I want to make function myself for ridge regression instead of using R packages.
I also need some learning material about ridge, although I have but not enough I feel.

Comment: @itfeature.com, if you want to "build you own", you just have to create a piece of software that minimizes $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - x_i {\boldsymbol \beta})^2 + \lambda \sum_{j=1}^{p} \beta_{j}^2 $$ for a given data set and input value, $\lambda$. So you need to a) calculate this criterion function - for this look into the syntax for user defined functions - and b) optimize it as a function of ${\boldsymbol \beta} = \{\beta_1, ..., \beta_p \}$. For this you can either "build you own" again or use a built-in `R` routine for optimization, such as the `optim` function. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for glmnet.  It's a generalization of both lasso and ridge regression, that can do either one or a combination of both.